# Quickbooks: How to get customer with transactions list

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have managed to get list of quickbooks customers via PHP SDK

```
$dataService = $this->quickBookService->getDataService();
$customers = $dataService->Query("select * from Customer");
```

So the `$customers` have the list of customers **BUT i cannot find anywhere that how can i get the list of a customer transactions**

Like the following of a customer

[image: customer transaction list]

**How can i get a customer transactions list ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the Intuit Developer API reference? It shows all the things you can query.

Specifically:

- Estimates - `SELECT * FROM Estimate`
- Payments - `SELECT * FROM Payment`
- Invoices - `SELECT * FROM Invoice`
- etc. etc. etc.

Links:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/invoice#query-an-invoice
- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/estimate#query-an-estimate
- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/payment#query-a-payment

Comment: Yes i have read the docs, But i cannot find the transaction list of a customer query, How can i do that also they have this info https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/report-entities/transactionlist#the-transactionlist-object | But it doesn't return a customer transaction list instead it gives me null

Comment: You can query each individual object type, and combine them on your end to build the transaction list. If you're having trouble fetching a report, _post your code_ so that we can see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: i want to get customers and their invoices in quickbooks using php any help